# Не могу использовать классы из своей папки

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular2, asp.net-web-api

1)Встроил в проект MVC Ангуляр.
2) создал класс в компоненте работает:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{person.name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent
{

    person: Person = new Person("Roman");
}

export class Person
{
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) { this.name = name }
}
```

так все спокойно показывает в html

но как только класс Person я создаю в отдельной папке и автоматически ипортирую в компонент то он не работает

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from "../Models/Person";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{person.name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent
{

    person: Person = new Person("Roman");
}
```

и тип Person по цвету не отображается как класс. http://prntscr.com/hcu63e 
Где его еще зарегистрировать?

Comment: в консоли пишет http://prntscr.com/hcubpp

Comment: файл который хранит class Person объявлен как typescript файл?

Comment: вместо  `from "../Models/Person"` попробуйте  `from "./Models/Person"`